# What class is called first in Objective-C program?

Tags: objective-c, class, program-entry-point

In Java one can specify the class what class is called when program starts. It must have `public static void main` .. you know the drill.

How about in `Objective-C`? Of all the classes you may have present in your program which one is called first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The starting point is not in a class but in the `main` function, same as regular C:

```
int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
```

For an iOS app, this is generally generated for you and control is passed into your `UIApplicationMain`.

For more information, see the section on the main function in the docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html).

Comment: Does this mean there can only be 1 main?

Comment: @mac: Objective-C's `main()` function is exactly the same as C's `main()` function, since Objective-C is essentially C with OO bling. You don't find a `main` method in an Objective-C class as you would in other OO languages like Java and C#.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing called is `main`, just like in C. This function usually calls `UIApplicationMain`, which in turn creates the main application object, based on the contents of the bundle's plist file, and then executes the application's event loop.

Comment: Yeah, now that there surely are more iOS apps than Mac apps... :P

Comment: @BoltClock: Yes, I must confess that I am iOS-centric.